# Calling close() on a valid file descriptor for a COM port blocks forever if the device has been powered off on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, file-io, bluetooth, serial-port

I'm writing an application in C on Mac OS X that communicates with a Bluetooth device using COM ports. If the Bluetooth device is powered off after the connection has been made, subsequent calls to `close` block indefinitely. Note I am using `aio_read` and `aio_write` to read and write to the device.

If the device is left powered on, then `close` succeeds as expected.

Example:

```
/* Open the com port */
int fd = open (g_comName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_ASYNC );

/* Ensure fd is valid, do some work, then power off the Bluetooth device */

/* Wait until all aysnc io is complete */
while (aio_cancel(fd, NULL) == AIO_NOTCANCELED) {}

/* Application will hang here */
close(fd);
```

What am I doing wrong? My guess is the OS is waiting for confirmation from the device, but never gets anything. Is there anyway to force close the connection?

**Edit:**

As suggested, setting `O_NONBLOCK` did the trick:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC)
```

Comment: I would try using `O_NONBLOCK`